# Testing mailer 'from' header using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, actionmailer, rspec-rails

I am working on a ruby on rails project, where I am trying to test the 'from' header field but the test case fails.

Here is what I am setting in the mailer action

```
def some_actoin
  mail(to: xyz@example.com,
         from: '"Example" <service@example.com>',
         subject: "test subject")
  end
end
```

And in the rspec test case,

```
mail.from.should == '"Example" <service@example.com>'
```

My test case is failing with following error

```
expected: '"Example" <service@example.com>'
got: [service@example.com] (using ==)
```

Is is the wrong way to test **from-header title with from-header email address**?

Appreciates any help!

Comment: the polite thing is to accept a good answer

Answer (score 21):

The `mail.from` just contains the from email address. You'll want to test the display name too.

```
mail.from.should eq(['service@example.com'])
mail[:from].display_names.should eq(['Example'])
```

Comment: Sam, thanks for the quick reply. I guess we will be able to achieve the above by using 'mail gem'. Is there a way to test the display name without using 'mail gem'?

Comment: It seems like `display_names` will return encoded(?) values for UTF-8 so I couldn't use for test. Instead you can use `mail[:from].value`.(at least for Rails 5)